# File system is not clean (The partition is misaligned by 1024 bytes)

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

After trying ubuntu for years and finding it too complicated the latest 12.04 got me intrigued. But after installing the Disk utility is giving me this error. I've searched here and there for a solution but they all seems to complicated for me. Is there a simple answer or do I have to repartition and reinstall all?

Yours sincerely
Kim Hansen, Denmark.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xaa9693fe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    52430847    26214400   1c  Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2   *    52430848   315301800   131435476+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       315301886   975836294   330267204+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       443142144   975836294   266347075+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       315301888   430755839    57726976   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       430757888   443135999     6189056   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 7948 MB, 7948206080 bytes
81 heads, 10 sectors/track, 19165 cylinders, total 15523840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x06ebddd7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192    15523839     7757824    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Which part? the comment box says I have -700 characters left?

Comment: Sorted :) (the comment part not the disk) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/#tools) explains this problem.

The problem with misalignment lies with the partition editor. The partition editor that was used during installation defaulted to `Rounding off to nearest cylinder`. Whereas for newer installers it defaults to `Rounding off to nearest MB`.

Possible solutions ...

- Back up, repartition, and restore.
- Repartition and reinstall.
- Use GParted to resize/move the partition that has a problem without backup.

[image]

[Here is the official document on resizing](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm). It is old though and does not include the dropdownbox regating the MiB setting.
[Another one without images](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition).

Comment: Phew this sounds complicated :( I was hoping this would be the easy ubuntu but... The last part seems interesting but how do I do it in  rl. Is there a "how to" wiki or something alike I can use?

Comment: No matter what I choose I will say thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Apperently I'm not worthy for upvoting (vote up requires 15 reputation) your solution so i'll have to thank you the good old way :(

Answer (score 0):

Boot a Ubuntu live CD, and open the terminal (Dash -> terminal, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), or a virtual terminal tty session (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>)

Run the `fcsk` command for `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.

Check the partition you are looking for with `df`. Your main drive partition is probably `/dev/sda1`.

Ex:

```
fsck /dev/sda1
fsck /dev/sdb1
```

The reason I am telling you to do this from a live CD is because
it is dangerous to do this while the hard drives are mounted.

You also need root permissions to do this so precede the above `fsck` commands with `sudo`.

See how that goes.

EDIT: Oh looks like I got ninja'd... still...

Comment: Still good information! But I do not think fsck will fix this (afaik it does not touch the borders of logical partitions)

Comment: There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  44:7e/02, 45:27/00
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action

Comment: This was the result